# Android studio stuck at the splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just downloaded android studio and everything is setup, i.e. environment variable. But the studio is not opening, just the android studio logo is there in desktop

[image: Stuck after opening]

Even after hours, it's still the same.

The environment variable is setup like
system variable
JDK_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02

Comment: do you have free space on your disk?

Comment: Try run it as Administrator

Comment: You have the latest version?

Comment: I tried running it as administrator as well @MarkoFrelih

Comment: It's the latest version @MarcoAcierno

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819064/cannot-start-android-studio-android-studio-stuck-at-the-splash-screen which has a good answer.

Comment: Are you running this from the command-line? It could give useful debugging output (for example I realised it was trying to download files but got stuck because of a bad connection). Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Android studio is still in an early access version and can be subject to a lot of problems. Recently a bug with gradle caused the build to fail for a reason that seemed unlinked. I'm just pointing out that using Android studio is not risk-free. IMHO, you should at least backup your project as much as you can to avoid any problem.

Back to your question, Have you updated android studio recently? First thing you can try is reinstall android studio. Make sure to backup the sdk in case it gets deleted (I'm using mac and the sdk is in the app package's content. I'm not sure on windows, you can try to look in the installation folder). If it doesn't work, I would fill a bug report here and ask for help guide you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adt-dev

Comment: I've tried re installing, so you recommend me filing a bug report? Also, would I do it on the android list, since its Android Studio?

Comment: Yes,the best place would probably be here : guide you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adt-dev. Ask for help, explain your problem in details along with what you've tried - they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
My fix was to delete the related folders in my "user" folder (.android, etc.) and also the sdk folder in AppData.
Android Studio booted fine, then just asked me if I wanted to import any settings (no) to find the sdk folder (I created a new empty one) and it re-downloaded everything.
I'm sure this isn't the ideal option, but it did work!!!