# Cannot start Android Studio. Android Studio stuck at the splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not able to start the android studio. I have set java path in environment variables and Android studio is also latest version. I have tried to install and run administrator but no help.
Please help me...

Answer (score 43):

1. Open file Android Studio setup **directory/bin/idea.properties**
2. Add `disable.android.first.run=true` to tail
3. Restart AS.

Comment: Sorry but it did not help..:-(  It still stucks at splash screen..:-(

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the easy solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am really curious to know, where did you learn this?

Comment: It didn't do for me either..is there some sort of log file we can turn on its a pain that the latest "stable" version doesn't even come up

Answer (score 4):

Going through the Known issues page(https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues) found me the fix.

Comment: Oh, that is great Shanthan, it would be very nice if you could add the relevant parts directly into this answer :)

Comment: The official page is much better. All the other answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

#### Actual Solution

None of the answers here specify on *how* to debug the problem, you need to run the **`bin\studio.bat`** script in the terminal and inspect the actual Idea exceptions in order to fix the problem.

No need to re-install, delete precious configuration (and plugins, etc.). Just read the error message!

For me, this was the issue:

```
ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

This means the plugin manager is trying to listen on a port that is not available.  Is something listening on that port?  For me, it is the stupid "excluded ports" by Windows, so I simply stopped the service:
**`net stop winnat`** (as administrator), and confirmed that Android Studio started to work.

**Don't delete your configuration files**, especially if you don't want to re-configure your settings.  Just read the log provided by the **`bin\studio.bat`** script.

Comment: Can't believe this stupid bug still hasn't been present in Android Studio Dolphin on Windows 11 in 2014. The solution still works like a charm. **Google should display the console's error message, instead of getting the IDE stuck on the splash screen!** ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

You have to set these additional `PATH`s

```
ANDROID_HOME = your SDK directory (android-sdk)
PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Comment: Sorry i did not get you. I am using Windows 7 32bit OS

Comment: These are additional `PATH` you have to set

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me! Although the system environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` has been set by the installer, it was obviously wrong as it uses PowerShell variable syntax: `${Env:LOCALAPPDATA}\Android\android-sdk` changing it to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-sdk` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2016, the most recent canary needs the property written as as:

```
-Ddisable.android.first.run=true
```

otherwise it complains about missing `JAVA_HOME`. (using windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed mine android studio by changing the system language, you can set yours to English go to Control Panel->Region under formats tab change the format to English(United states).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by changing the system language. Set your language to English by going to the Control Panel/Region. In the Formats tab change the format to English(United states).

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded my Android Studio from 3.0 to 4.1 and after that AS always stuck on the splash screen. Fortunately, this section of the known-issues works for me https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my Android Studio by changing the system language. You can set yours to English by going to:

> Control Panel->Region

Under the formats tab, change the format to:

> English(United states)

Thanks @ravi this also worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2022, I was stuck in the splash screen was due to a plug-in conflict, but the IDE wasn't warning about it.

I received a warning balloon saying that I had the ExcelReader plug-in installed, suggesting me to install the new ExcelEditor plug-in, which is an improved (and paid ¬¬) version (I knew later). So I went and installed it and the IDE suggested restarting.

After restarting, the IDE always got stuck in the splash screen every single time I tried to launch it.

It wasn't until an hour later and so many launch attempts that, miraculously, the IDE launched and a dialog showed up warning about both plug-ins being not compatible so I had to disable one of them. It was a shame that it didn't warn me before. So I chose which one to disable on the dialog and it worked again.

Therefore, I suppose that if this were to happen again, it could be solved by editing the file */home/$USER/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/disabled_plugins.txt* and adding the plug-in to the file manually.

In my case it was "com.chesterccw.excelreader" what I should have added. After that, of course, I uninstalled one of the plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Studio doesn't start after upgrade

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

```
Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio<version>
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio<version>
Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio<version> and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio<version>
Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

For Android Studio 4.0 and earlier:

```
Windows: %HOMEPATH%\.AndroidStudio<version>\config
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.6\config

macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio<version>
Example: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.6

Linux: ~/.AndroidStudio<version>/config
Example: ~/.AndroidStudio3.6/config
```

Note that the configuration directory for Canary and Beta releases of Android Studio is PreviewX.Y instead of X.Y for the . For example, Android Studio 4.1 Canary builds use AndroidStudioPreview4.1, instead of the AndroidStudio4.1 directory that is used for Release Candidates and Stable releases.

https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues

Answer (score 0):

Well if the problem is plugin born, then this is the only solution that worked for me (on debian linux)

1)

```bash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/
```

or

```bash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2022.2/
```

-- replace with your version

2. start android studio
3. works ;)

Answer (score -1):

just add this line     disable.android.first.run=true      at the bottom of the idea.properties file in the bin directory of the installation folder

Comment: Format your answer and add more details