# Android Studio 2.2.3 freeze when launching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2.3

When i try to run Android Studio it gets suspended and not launching.
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR6NH.png)

I've tried several things such as:
[Cannot start Android Studio. Android Studio stuck at the splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819064/cannot-start-android-studio-android-studio-stuck-at-the-splash-screen)

Currently it is not working. It happens to me several times, and i always uninstall it and install older version - then it works. It is really annoying solution, how get this working correctly by not using my solution? 
My OS is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start Android Studio. Android Studio stuck at the splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819064/cannot-start-android-studio-android-studio-stuck-at-the-splash-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `.AndroidStudio2.3` folder or any version of it from this location `C:\Users\UserName\`.